# adding option "--enable-https" to GraalVM gradle nativeCompile task

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm, spring-native

I am trying to build an executive via the `compileNative` task from a Spring Boot 3.0.0M5 project.

I need to add the `--enable-https` to the GraalVM compiler.

How is it possible to add that option using the gradle plugin?

```
id "org.graalvm.buildtools.native" version "0.9.14"
```

Answer (score 0):

it is done by adding this to the `build.gradle`

```
graalvmNative {
    binaries {
        main {
            buildArgs.add('--enable-https')
        }
    }
}
```